# Read data from column and compare it to current time

Tags: batch-file

I am very newbie to coding and trying to both learn & accomplish an automation program. I have .csv file which has columns like

```
"411|487","41164","48036"
```

The second column "41164" is the time to seconds when the process completed. So for example if the time is 14:07 this column would be 14*60*60 + 07*60 = 50820

The third column in the line "48036" is the time to seconds which is the process should be repeated. So if the current time to seconds is more than COLUMN3, my macro program repeats that columns process. My problem is I have a lot of lines and the macro program I use cannot make a total calculation to find which lines` process should be repeated. It tries all of them one by one to find them and that means a lot of waste of time, so I should make the csv ready for it. With the code below

```
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=3 Delims=, " %%A In ("example.csv") Do (
    Echo %%~A)>>"example2.csv"
```

I'm getting all the column3 data in the example.csv and write it into example2.csv without quotos then in the same for I tried to calculate current time to seconds and substract it from %%~A with

```
set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set /a hourtosec=%hour%*60*60
set /a minutetosec=%minute%*60
set /a totalsec=%hourtosec% + %minutetosec%
set /a repeat=%AA-%totalsec%
Echo %repeat%)>>"example2.csv"
```

but it doesn't work. Repeat output is wrong. How can I substract the %totalsec% from %AA and write it in a file?

Comment: `%AA`?? Sure, you don't want `%%A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for you, which outputs to a new file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Inp=example.csv"
Set "Out=example2.csv"
If Not Exist "%Inp%" Exit /B
Set "Repeat="
Set "Now=%TIME%"
(   For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=3 Delims=," %%A In ("%Inp%") Do (Echo %%~A
        Set /A "Repeat=%%~A-((100%Now:~,2%%%100)*60*60)+(100%Now:~3,2%%%100)*60)"
        Call Echo %%Repeat%%))>"%Out%"
If Not Defined Repeat Del "%Out%"
```

You could also append to an existing output file, *this version also uses delayed expansion*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Inp=example.csv"
Set "Out=example2.csv"
If Not Exist "%Inp%" Exit /B
Set "Now=%TIME%"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(   For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=3 Delims=," %%A In ("%Inp%") Do (Echo %%~A
        Set /A "Repeat=%%~A-((100%Now:~,2%%%100)*60*60)+(100%Now:~3,2%%%100)*60)"
        Echo !Repeat!))>>"%Out%"
EndLocal
```